Find all positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that $3x^2+2x+92=3y^2$.
Find all positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that $3x^2+2x+92=3y^2$.
Since the RHS is a multiple of $3$, then so is the LHS. Hence, $x=3k+2$ for some non-negative integer $k$. I found that $x=2$ and $x=8$ satisfies the condition by inspection on small values of $k$. But, I didn't know to find the others if any.
Any ideas? Many thanks in advanced.

It's a finite problem.  Since $3(n+1)^2-3n^2=6n+3$ we see that the least $3y^2-3x^2$ can be is $6x+3$.  Thus $6x+3≤2x+92\implies 4x≤89\implies x<23$.

This is a finite problem.  Since $x,y>0$ we must have $y>x$.  But $(x+1)^2-x^2=2x+1$ so $3y^2-3x^2≥6x+3$.
It follows that $$6x+3≤2x+92\iff 4x≤89\iff x≤22$$
A simple search then confirms that the OP has found the only two solutions: $(x,y)=(2,6)$ and $(x,y)=(8,10)$.

Multiplying both sides by 3 yields $$9x^2+6x+276=9y^2$$
$$(3x+1)^2+275=(3y)^2$$
$$(3y-3x-1)(3y+3x+1)=5^2\times11$$
If we want $x$ and $y$ positive, we want to factor $275$ into a larger factor equivalent to $1$ modulo $3$ and a smaller factor equivalent to $-1$ modulo $3$.  $55\times5$ and $25\times11$ work.  If $3y+3x+1=55$ and $3y-3x-1=5$, then $6x+2=50$ and $x=8$.  Similarly, the other possibility gives $6x+2=14,x=2$.
